# What's the precise definition of self-similarity of the Cantor set?

Tags: fractals, cantor-set

> What's the precise definition of self-similarity of the Cantor set $C$?

It seems we have left and right transformations which each transform the set onto congruent proper subsets of itself whose union is the set itself:

$$T_L(x)=\frac{x}{3}$$

$$T_R(x)=\frac{x+2}{3}$$

Now [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Self-similarity) says $T_L(C)\cong T_R(C)\cong C$ which is true, but but I'm not clear if congruence is a sufficiently precise relation and if it's perhaps a mistake to state such a trivial relation because if I understand congruence correctly, $T_L(X)\cong T_R(X)\cong X$ for pretty much any set of points $X$ on the real line.

What IS unique about the Cantor set is that $T_L(C)\cong T_R(C)\cong T_L(C)\cup T_R(C)$

And the most precise statement it seems to me is:

$$C=T_L(C)\cup T_R(C)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set $A\subset{\mathbb R}^d$ is *self similar* if
$$A=\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\ ,$$
whereby $A_k=T_k(A)$ for similarities $T_k:\>{\mathbb R}^d\to{\mathbb R}^d$ $(1\leq k\leq n)$, and the $A_k$ are "almost disjoint" (The exact definition is quite technical. Intuitively the intersections $A_j\cap A_k$ have to be less fat than the $A_k$ themselves.) In the relevant cases the $T_k$ all have scaling factors $\lambda_k<1$.

For the Cantor set we have $d=1$,  $n=2$, and scaling factors $\lambda_k={1\over3}$.

Comment: Thanks. In suitably brief terms, how is "almost disjoint" different to "disjoint"?  I presume these are not mutually exclusive concepts as the Cantor example the sets appear to be disjoint.

Comment: Does "almost disjoint" means something pretty close to: their limit under union converges to a subset of $\Bbb{R}^d$ but not in finitely many steps?